# howto use int16multiarray in python

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
how do i use int16multiarray in  python ? when i got this code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
# license removed for brevity
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from std_msgs.msg import Int16MultiArray


def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('mytopic', Int16MultiArray, queue_size=1)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(1) # 1hz

    hello_float = Int16MultiArray()
    hello_float.data = []


    a=0
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        if a==0:
                hello_float.data = []
                hello_float.data.insert(0, [380,399,380,380,380,380,380,380] )
                rospy.loginfo(hello_float)
                pub.publish(hello_float)
                a=1
        elif a==1:
                hello_float.data = []
                hello_float.data.insert(0, [377,399,380,380,380,380,380,380] )
                rospy.loginfo(hello_float)
                pub.publish(hello_float)
                a=0


        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

with this, i get the following error:

```
 rosrun pub_float_test talker.py 
[INFO] [WallTime: 1465990335.722463] layout: 
  dim: []
  data_offset: 0
data: 
  - [380, 399, 380, 380, 380, 380, 380, 380]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1465990336.723584] layout: 
  dim: []
  data_offset: 0
data: 
  - [377, 399, 380, 380, 380, 380, 380, 380]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/pub_float_test/nodes/talker.py", line 37, in <module>
    talker()
  File "/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/pub_float_test/nodes/talker.py", line 29, in talker
    pub.publish(hello_float)
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 852, in publish
    self.impl.publish(data)
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 1036, in publish
    serialize_message(b, self.seq, message)
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 152, in serialize_message
    msg.serialize(b)
  File "/opt/ros/jade/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/_Int16MultiArray.py", line 114, in serialize
    except struct.error as se: self._check_types(struct.error("%s: '%s' when writing '%s'" % (type(se), str(se), str(_x))))
UnboundLocalError: local variable '_x' referenced before assignment
```

how do i clear a int16Multiarray ? there is no hello_float.data.clear() like in c ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237063/howto-use-int16multiarray-in-python/) by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 406 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In both cases of the if-elif statement, when you type the line `hello_float.data = []` you are setting the data field to be an empty Python list. Then when you call `insert` you are inserting a new list into the zeroth entry of the original list. In other words, you are making the `hello_float.data` field a list of lists. This is most likely what is causing your error.

Your loop could instead read

```
a=0
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    if a==0:
            hello_float.data = [380,399,380,380,380,380,380,380]
            rospy.loginfo(hello_float)
            pub.publish(hello_float)
            a=1
    elif a==1:
            hello_float.data = [377,399,380,380,380,380,380,380]
            rospy.loginfo(hello_float)
            pub.publish(hello_float)
            a=0
    rate.sleep()
```

and it would work fine. Pre Python 3.3, there is no list `clear()` method. Check out [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850795/clearing-python-lists).

Note that the Int16MultiArray field can only be a one dimensional list. If you are trying to publish a matrix (or some other arbitrary multi-dimensional array), you will need to flatten that array into a single list and publish that. The fields in the `dim` array tell a subscriber how to unpack the flattened list correctly. For more details check out the documentation on the [MultiArrayLayout message](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/MultiArrayLayout.html) or [this demo](https://gist.github.com/jarvisschultz/7a886ed2714fac9f5226) I made a while back that shows how to publish a random 3x3 matrix in Python and subscribe/unpack into an Eigen matrix in C++.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) on 2016-06-15**:
thanks alot